# How to select field with particular value or null from joined table

Tags: sql

maybe my description is bit misty:)
i want to do outer join on two tables, and select records where one field has some value or is null
my original concept was

```
select A.x,B.y 
from A 
left outer join B 
    on A.id= B.a_id 
where b.y ='abc' 
    or b.y is null
```

but then i realized it's taking B.y from  B table not from joined
is it any easy fix how i can do it?

what i need is selecting rows, where B.y is 'abc' or null, ie :
(1,'abc')
(2,null)

while my query gives me functionality of inner join with result

(1,'abc')
ignoring other entry

Comment: What exactly is your question?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it

```
select A.x,B.y from A left outer join B on A.id= B.a_id and ( b.y ='abc' or b.y is null )
```

After reading comments just remove left outer

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
    select A.x,b.y 
    from A 
    left outer join B 
        on A.id= B.a_id and
        b.y ='abc'
```

If, as you say in your comment, you're getting inner join results instead of your expected outer join, it's because you're referencing your outer table in your where clause.
You need to move the reference to the join.

Comment: You should change `==` with `=`

Comment: nope, i want field y from field B even if it's null, and my using '==' instead '=' was just typo, im using much more java than sql, so im more used to == statement:)

Comment: OK, well, you said the problem was "it's taking B.y from B table not from joined"  If you want B.y from the B table, then what's your question?

Comment: @Beth, what i meant is, my query gave me functionality of inner join